# .NET WinForms WebBrowser control throws exception when navigating to IPv6 address

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, ipv6

I have a WinForms web browser control. When I call [Navigate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with an IPv6 address, I get an ArgumentException, which isn't a documented exception for the call. Does the WebBrowser control simply not support IPv6 addresses?

```
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Navigate2(Object& URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigate2(Object& URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigateHelper(String urlString, Boolean newWindow, String targetFrameName, Byte[] postData, String headers)
   at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(String urlString)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the ip v6 address in brackets [ ]

See reference here

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-can-ipv6-address-used-with-webbrowser/

Hopefully that works from the web browser control as well.

Comment: It did prevent the exception from happening. I wasn't able to navigate to the address, but that could be due to a limitation on the host machine or the network i'm on in general.